# Bitmasking--when to use hex vs binary

Tags: algorithm, binary, hex, bit-manipulation, bitmask

I'm working on a problem out of Cracking The Coding Interview which requires that I swap odd and even bits in an integer with as few instructions as possible (e.g bit 0 and 1 are swapped, bits 2 and 3 are swapped, etc.)

The author's solution revolves around using a mask to grab, in one number, the odd bits, and in another num the even bits, and then shifting them off by 1.

I get her solution, but I don't understand how she grabbed the even/odd bits. She creates two bit masks --both in hex -- for a 32 bit integer. The two are: 0xaaaaaaaa and 0x55555555. I understand she's essentially creating the equivalent of 1010101010... for a 32 bit integer in hexadecimal and then ANDing it with the original num to grab the even/odd bits respectively.

What I don't understand is why she used hex? Why not just code in 10101010101010101010101010101010? Did she use hex to reduce verbosity? And when should you use one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's to reduce verbosity. Binary 10101010101010101010101010101010, hexadecimal 0xaaaaaaaa, and decimal 2863311530 all represent *exactly* the same value; they just use different bases to do so. The only reason to use one or another is for perceived readability.

- Most people would clearly not want to use decimal here; it looks like an arbitrary value.
- The binary is clear: alternating 1s and 0s, but with so many, it's not obvious that this is a 32-bit value, or that there isn't an adjacent pair of 1s or 0s hiding in the middle somewhere.
- The hexadecimal version takes advantage of chunking. Assuming you recognize that `0x0a == 0b1010`, you can mentally picture the 8 groups of 1010 in the assumed value.
- Another possibility would be octal 25252525252, since... well, maybe not. You can see that *something* is alternating, but unless you use octal *a lot*, it's not clear what that alternating pattern in binary is.

Comment: So you can use a mask in any base without issue?

Comment: Yes; it's the same *value*, regardless of the base used. They are all just different ways of writing "two billion, eight hundred sixty-three million, three hundred eleven thousand, five hundred thirty". Binary and hexadecimal simply help make it more obvious *why* this particular value is being used.